# Date axis needed next to a gojs swim lane diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, activity-diagram, gojs

I am prototyping a web application in which I would like to display a vertical swim lane activity diagram and a custom date axis next to the diagram. The nodes of the diagram should be positioned according to their date attribute. The user should be possible to "zoom in and out" changing the scale of the date axis. I am using gojs for the activity diagram and d3.js for the date axis and my effort so far can be found in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johnecon/c0mbgmd5/)

As you can see, the axis is getting out of the scrollable `"#myDiagram"` div and it is not "well attached" to the diagram (the diagram can be dragged and the axis is not following).

My questions are:

- is there an easier way to display a date axis in a gojs diagram?
- is it possible to add custom html in a gojs diagram? ([geometry strings](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/icons.html) seems to be the only custom solution for developers)

Any help/suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting this question to the [gojs forum](http://forum.nwoods.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=6086&title=date-axis-next-to-swim-lane-diagram) I got the following answer:

> No, GoJS doesn't have built-in support for timelines.  But you could
> look at some samples, such as https://gojs.net/latest/samples/timeline.html and
> http://gojs.net/temp/swimbands2.html.